# Using hibernate with existing database

Tags: hibernate, legacy-database

I want to use hibernate against an existing database.  I need to mostly read data from the db and very occasionally modify a field.

I want to be able to update a single field in the row, but i need to make sure that all the other fields are not touched.

Does hibernate guarantee that a field will be written back the same as it was written (assuming i haven't modified the object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the other fields insertable=false, updateable=false should work.
It should tell Hibernate that update on those field won't be reflected in DB

Comment: i ended up using this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to update a single field in the row, but i need to make sure that all the other fields are not touched.

That's possible if you use "[dynamic updates](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class)". Here is what the documentation writes about this setting:

> dynamic-update (optional - defaults to false): specifies that UPDATE SQL should be generated at runtime and can contain only those columns whose values have changed.

If you don't use this, all writable (see [insert, update](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property)) properties will be part of the update.

But if you didn't change anything values, Hibernate won't change them on your back.